# exclude directories from control mercurial

Tags: gwt, mercurial

I have my GWT project set up with hg for version control, and want to exclude the generated  files in the war/modulename folder entirely.

I would prefer not to have to use an --exclude switch with every command.  Is there a preferences file I can use to regularly exclude the directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use .hgignore file.** Basically, you can create a .hgignore file in the directory or repo

Please look at the following SO discussion. It answers most of what you need.

- [Mercurial: a few questions all related to .hgignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510044/mercurial-a-few-questions-all-related-to-hgignore)
- [Mercurial .hgignore for Visual Studio 2008 projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784/mercurial-hgignore-for-visual-studio-2008-projects)
- [Would like to create some defaults for my .hgignore files in TortoiseHG/Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785609/would-like-to-create-some-defaults-for-my-hgignore-files-in-tortoisehg-mercurial)
- http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html
- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/.hgignore

> The two different syntax in .hgignore
>   file are glob and regexp. The SO posts
>   and link to Mercurial documentation
>   should make that clear.

A typical file can contain both types of syntax.

```
# use glob syntax.
syntax: glob

*.elc
*.pyc
*~

# switch to regexp syntax.
syntax: regexp
^\.pc/
```

As an example, the following ignores the files created during merge

```
syntax:regexp

\.orig$
\.orig\..*$
\.chg\..*$
\.rej$
\.conflict\~$
```

Answer (score 4):

To ignore a whole directory add the following to a [.hgignore](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) file in the root of your checkout:

```
war/modulename
```

If you just want a few files you could have a line something like so:

```
war/modulename/*.extension
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SourceFolder `.hgignore` use the following:

The solution, for folders named `gen` and `bin` and a file named `.classpath`:

```
syntax: regexp  
^SourceFolder\bin  
^SourceFolder\gen  
^SourceFolder\.classpath
```